# Регулярное выражение для данных по шаблону= "3 или 4 символа" "пробел" "1 символ минимум"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь сделать регулярное выражение для проверки данных по шаблону.
"3 или 4 символа" "пробел"  "1 символ минимум"
Пример,

написано, "LED Санкт-Петербург"
минимум должно быть написано "LED С"

Comment: `^[\u0020-\uFFFF]{3,4}` поддерживает не ASCII символы и диапазон исключает управляющие символы  https://regex101.com/r/mVtC31/1/

Comment: спасибо, к сожалению не подошло. в DAX2012 оказалось, что по-другому работают выражения, проверки на regex101 подошли

Comment: `[^ ]{3,4} .+` может быть такое сработает?